# Perdida de datos entre clases de misma capa (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Situación: quiero pasar los datos de login desde capa visual a logica y posterior datos, para obtener una respuesta de rol del usuario que ingresa.
Problema: los datos de login que se ingresan en la capa visual, llegan con éxito hasta la clase para Usuarios de la capa de datos, pero no logro que lleguen a la superclase de clase de conexión ni al módulo donde tengo los parametros para conectarme a la BD.
Los códigos:

Clase Modelo de conexion, (superclase)

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public MustIhnerit Class Conexion
    Public User As String
    Public Pass As String
    Public DB As String
    Public IP As String

    Public conexion As New OdbcConnection
    Public comando As New OdbcCommand
    Public lector As OdbcDataReader

    Public Sub New()
        MsgBox(StringConexion)
        'Este MsgBox muestra vacíos los campos Usuario y Password, es el String para realizar la conexión.
        Me.conexion.ConnectionString = ParametrosDB.StringConexion
        Me.conexion.Open()
        Me.comando.Connection = Me.conexion
    End Sub
End Class
```

Clase modelo de conexion por consultas de usuario (para login, obtener el rol del usuario etc, al momento solo intento obtener el rol)

```
Public Class Usuarios
    Inherits Conexion
    Public ro As Integer
    Public User
    Public Pass

    Public Function ObtenerRol()
        MsgBox("Usuario: " + Me.User + "; Password: " + Me.Pass) 
        'Este MsgBox muestra los datos que ingresé sin problemas
        Dim sql = "SELECT fk_rol_empl FROM EMPLEADO WHERE USUARIO = '" + Me.User + "'"
        Me.comando.CommandText = sql
        lector = Me.comando.ExecuteReader()
        Return ro
    End Function

End Class
```

Módulo al que no llegan los datos:

```
Module ParametrosDB

    Public IP = "192.168.50.5"
    Public Usuario = ""
    Public DB = "baseproyecto"
    Public Password = ""

    Public StringConexion = "DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};
                UID=" + Usuario + ";
                PWD=" + Password + ";
                DATABASE=" + DB + ";
                HOST=" + IP + ";
                SERVER=ol_esi;
                SERVICE=9088;
                PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;
                CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;
                DB_LOCALE=en_US.819"
    End Module
```

Clase Lógica para Usuario

```
Imports CapaDeDatos

Public Class Usuario


    Public Function ConsultarRol(ByVal usuario, ByVal password)
        Dim rolObt As Integer
        Dim r As New Usuarios
        r.User = usuario
        r.Pass = password

        rolObt = r.ObtenerRol()

        Return rolObt

    End Function
End Class
```

El formulario de la capa visual

```
Imports CapaLogica


Public Class frmLogin
    Private Sub btnAceptar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIngresar.Click

        If txtUsuario.Text.Trim = "" Or txtPassword.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("Ambos campos son obligatorios")
         End If

         Dim o As New Usuario
         Dim rol As Integer
         rol = o.ConsultarRol(txtUsuario.Text, txtPassword.Text)

         If rol Then
            MsgBox("Bienvenido.")
            MsgBox("rolobtenido = " & rol)
            frmMenuAdmin.Show()
            Me.Hide()
         Else
            MsgBox("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.")
            MsgBox("rolobtenido = " & rol)
         End If
    End Sub
```

End Class

Como los datos de Usuario y Password no llegan al módulo no puedo ingresar a la BD.
Dato que me alarma, es que con todos los msgbox que estoy utilizando para del debug, poniendo uno en la clase de cada capa, el orden en que los muestra es desde capa de datos hacia visual, cuando creo debería ser al contrario, que me dicen?

```
Gracias.
```

Comment: No veo donde estas usando informix (la db no importa para tu problema). Ahi agregue una respuesta. Voy a borrar los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu clase usuario hereda de la clase conexion.

Entonces la primer clase que se va a generar cuando instancies la clase usuario, va a ser la clase conexion.

El constructor de la clase conexion, no tiene las propiedades de la clase usuario.

Y como si fuera poco, hiciste lo siguiente:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public MustIhnerit Class Conexion
    Public User As String
    Public Pass As String
```

Y en la clase que hereda de esta:

```
Public Class Usuarios
    Inherits Conexion
    Public ro As Integer
    Public User
    Public Pass
```

O sea, que sobreescribiste las variables User y Pass de la clase padre. Por lo tanto, la clase padre no recibe User y Pass, porque se quedan en la clase hija.

Tu otro problema, es que la funcion ObtenerRol no hace nada

```
Public Function ObtenerRol()
    MsgBox("Usuario: " + Me.User + "; Password: " + Me.Pass) 
    'Este MsgBox muestra los datos que ingresé sin problemas
    Dim sql = "SELECT fk_rol_empl FROM EMPLEADO WHERE USUARIO = '" + Me.User + "'"
    Me.comando.CommandText = sql
    lector = Me.comando.ExecuteReader()
    'no hiciste nada con lector, ro no tiene nada para devolver.
    Return ro
End Function
```

Una vez que ejecutar el reader, deberias recorrerlo para obtener sus valores. Igual en este caso, como solo queres devolver un valor, te recomendaria usar [ExecuteScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8) que te va a devolver el primer dato del primer registro de tu query, que es lo que vos queres. Tambien, chequea que ese dato no sea nulo, que es lo que va a pasar si tu query no encuentra lo que estas buscando.

Comment: Lo del reader estaba en standby por lo de la conexion... sin conexion no podia seguir.
Y la clase que hereda debería ser Usuarios, ya que luego voy a tener vehiculos, inspecciones, y otras que deberían heredar de conexion, como Usuarios.... no?

Comment: Es raro.. porque en general se usa una sola conexion y vos asi tendrias una conexion por clase.. pero si.. puede ser.. @Vizz3rdriX ahora entendiste tus problemas?

Comment: creo que si, mañana cuando pueda agarrarlo al 100% sin distracciones te cuento, pero igual, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y por aguantarme